# How to keep only one colorbar for animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, matplotlib-animation

I'm attempting to create an animation with the Matplotlib animation package in Python. However, I'm encountering an issue where multiple colorbars appear in the animation. This could be because the colorbar in each subsequent frame isn't overwriting the previous one. I would greatly appreciate it if a solution could be provided. You can find the code and GIF I'm using below.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter
import numpy as np


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def animate(i):
    ax.clear()
    np.random.seed(i)
    z = np.random.rand(20, 20)
    im = ax.imshow(z, origin='lower')

    cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, orientation='vertical')


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=20, interval=5, repeat=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHW5U.gif)

Comment: If the colorbar is the same for all frames, why not create the colorbar outside of the animation function?

Answer (score 0):

Before the animation starts, at frame 0, you must initialize an initial z array.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter
import numpy as np


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

z = np.random.rand(20, 20)
im = ax.imshow(z, origin='lower')

cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, orientation='vertical')

def animate(i):
    global z, im, cbar

    ax.clear()
    cbar.remove()
    
    np.random.seed(i)
    z = np.random.rand(20, 20)
    im = ax.imshow(z, origin='lower')

    cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, orientation='vertical')


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=20, interval=5, repeat=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```